# Spouse visa for multiple entry to the US

Tags: visas, spouses

I am a US citizen living abroad. My wife is a Polish national living abroad. Our child is a dual national.

Neither of us intend to live in the US anytime soon, but we would like to visit the US frequently.

When I google “US spouse visa” all hits concern acquiring a green card, which is just not relevant for us.

What’s the name of the visa we should apply for?

The trouble with B2 is that it’s only good for up to six months

> The Visitor Visa is a nonimmigrant visa for persons desiring to enter
>   the United States temporarily for business (B1), including attending
>   professional meetings or conference; for pleasure, including vacation
>   or visiting family or medical treatment (B2), or a combination of both
>   (B1/B2) purposes for up to six months.

Answer (score 5):

Your wife should apply for a [B-2 visitor visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html).  Barring any unusual circumstances, it should be issued for a period of [ten years](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/Visa-Reciprocity-and-Civil-Documents-by-Country/Poland.html).

As the spouse of a US citizen, your wife may have more difficulty proving a lack of immigrant intent than most Polish applicants would, so she might want to include evidence showing *your* ties to your place of residence as well as her own.

Comment: What kind of evidence would be suitable to those ends? For ex my ownership and our residency in a house in our third county of residence? My permanent contract with an employer here? Anything else?

Comment: @Teusz that's probably fine.  Anything that tends to show you'll return should do the trick.

Comment: The trouble with a b2 visa is that it’s only good for up to six months. So we would need to renew it, no?

Comment: @Teusz That's six months per visit.  Any longer and yeah, you're looking at residency.

Comment: @PeterM B-2 visitors can actually be admitted for up to one year, but that is very rare in practice.

Comment: @Teusz the B-2 visa is normally issued for ten years for citizens of most countries, [including Poland](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/Visa-Reciprocity-and-Civil-Documents-by-Country/Poland.html).